# How to populate a List View with data from an xml file in SD card?

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, xml-parsing

I am  developing password managment app with a ListView to show the username, and details they have entered.

[image]

I am using

> viewpass.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewPasses"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>



</LinearLayout>
```

and for a custom listitem in the listview

> listviewitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#2C5924">

    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSite"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Site:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAdditional"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Additional:"
        android:lines="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I want read this xml file from the sd card and load this in the listView

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>
<site>linux.comn</site>
<username> root </username>
<password>md5hashedvalue</password>
<additional>Additional info</additional>
</info>
```

Can anyone give me a method to load the listview.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `ListView`, it's more complicated and what you want is very easy. You can use `TextView` and `SharedPreferences`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

// then put user's name in OnClick method

    prefs.putString("name", name_string);


//you can get name like this from everywhere: 

    String myName = prefs.getString("name", "");

//and show it in a `TextView`, not a `ListView`

    nameTV.setText(myName);
```

Comment: i want to show all the data of different users,in one listview